# Android Google Firestore Notify user app that there is new data in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an android app that uses both Room and Firestore.
The app will have a long list of items that are stored in Firestore. When the user first launches the app the app will read all the items from the Firestore and store them in Room and from then on the users app will read the item list from Room. 
Now, this item list will change but only about once a month so I need a system where I can update the list in Firestore and then send a message to all users that the items list has changed. They must then do a one time fetch to get the updated items list from Firestore and write it to Room.

Using Firestore listener is not an option as this will result in hundreds of unnecessary reads every time a user opens the item list activity.

Also Firebase Cloud Messaging only seems to be recieved by users whos apps are online.

Is there a way to notify all users apps (even those that are offline) that the data set has changed and that they must execute a fetch and retrieve the updated item list?
Is there a way to force users to check for new messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging whenever the app starts so they can get the updated item list?

Comment: What is Room? Got a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using FCM to serve this information, I would integrate a "list" version number into a document that is accessed whenever you start up the app.

For example, it's common to have a service status document (such as `/global/status`) that contains important meta information such as latest application versions for your mobile apps (to show "Please update" messages), information about upcoming outages or links/IDs to blog posts that you use to serve news/messages to your users.

If you have a suitable document, you would add an entry for "listVersion" that could be a timestamp, a version number or the like. If using a version number, you have the added benefit of being able to use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org) and give it special meaning. Update immediately for major changes, prompt the user to update their database (if on mobile data) for minor changes and maybe update only over WiFi in the background if it's only a patch (such as fixing a typo somewhere). To mix the version number with a timestamp, just use the year and month as the major and minor versions and keep the patch number as is (e.g. `v2019.11.28`). The meaning of each version is up to you as how you are updating the list and it's purpose is not known.

Comment: thanks but your answer is the behavior I am trying to avoid. Having a list version # stored locally that gets checked every time the app launches means that the app needs to fetch the current list version # from Firestore every time the app launches which will result in tons of unnecessary reads. I need to send out a message to all instances of the app (whether in foreground, background, powered off, or anything in between) and set a flag that lets the app itself (not the users) know there are new list items so the next time the app opens the app can go retrieve the list items from Firestore